# How to use cookie which is created using the rememberMe() feature of spring security in springboot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, cookies, spring-security

I am learning spring boot and creating a simple web based project where I have created a cookie using the remember me feature of Spring security, but don't know how to use that cookie for extracting information of the session.

For e.g. displaying this on a page - "hello {user}", user being passed from the page to page. {user} value should come from the cookie along with the other information.

Can we go by this way? If yes, how to extract the user information from the cookie or is there any other way to achieve the particular functionality?

I tried to do a search for this, but could not find a concrete solution.

Here is a part of the code.

```
.rememberMe()
        .alwaysRemember(true)
        .tokenValiditySeconds(30)
        .rememberMeCookieName("saurabh")
        .key("somesecret");
```

Comment: To implement the solution, the person who asked the question is using spring-security XML. He is adding all the tags at the XML file and then printing the same in the JSP

Comment: No, neither the question or any answer are using XML, it is all about JSP. Where do you see XML?

Comment: @dur I have added the picture of the ans for the reference. You can see Jeremiah who asked the question is implementing the solution using XML tags.

Comment: That is only a comment. It is not relevant for the question or for any answer.

Answer (score 0):

All of this is already taken care of for you inside the [`RememberMeAuthenticationFilter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/f221920a1990f458b26b185c8fbe5b3623dbd8c1/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/rememberme/RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java#L64)

That filter gets inserted, and does the following

1. Checks to see if there is any information available

```java
Authentication rememberMeAuth = 
    rememberMeServices.autoLogin(request, response);
```

2. If there is information, it gives the authentication manager a chance to reject it or authenticate the user properly

```java
rememberMeAuth = authenticationManager.authenticate(rememberMeAuth);
```

3. Stores the information in the SecurityContext (you are now authenticated)

```java
 SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(rememberMeAuth);
```

4. Calls a No-Op metho

```java
 onSuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, rememberMeAuth);
```

5. Fires the events

```java
 eventPublisher.publishEvent(new InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent(...));
```

6. And finally, if configured, fires the Success Handler

```java
 successHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response,
                            rememberMeAuth);
```

If you want to intercept this chain of events, do so in your `AuthenticationManager`. Step 2, where Spring will pass the information to you.